# How to extract attribute from HTTP

Tags: c#, http

I'm trying to capture a team's schedule from HTTP.
But what I do so far is like this:

```
2018/1/23 Tuesday   AM4:00  Swansea Ci      Liverpool
```

but I need to do like this:

```
2018/1/23 Tuesday   AM4:00  Swansea City    Liverpool
```

It's because I set the string length as 10, so it won't print the "ty"
So how can I make it right in this code structure? THX!

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public class Crawler
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string web = "http://www.goal.com/hk/fixtures/team/liverpool/663";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(web);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string line0 = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string path = @"C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\LiverpoolSchedule.txt";
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                string SS0 = @"2...年.?.?月.?.?日星期.?</th>\n<th colspan=";
                foreach (Match match0 in Regex.Matches(line0, SS0))
                {
                    writer.Write(match0.ToString().Remove(match0.ToString().IndexOf("</th>")));
                    writer.Write("\t");

                    string SS1 = @"<td class=.status.>\n.午.?.?:.?.?";
                    string line1 = line0.Substring(match0.Index);
                    Match match1 = Regex.Match(line1, SS1);
                    writer.Write(match1.ToString().Substring(match1.ToString().IndexOf("\n") + 1));
                    writer.Write("\t");

                    string SS2 = @".png. alt=.";
                    string line2 = line1.Substring(match1.Index);
                    Match match2 = Regex.Match(line2, SS2);
                    writer.Write(line2.Substring(match2.Index + 11, 10));
                    writer.Write("\t");

                    string SS3 = @".png. alt=.";
                    string line3 = line2.Substring(match2.Index + 30);
                    Match match3 = Regex.Match(line3, SS3);
                    writer.Write(line3.Substring(match3.Index + 11, 10));
                    writer.WriteLine();
                }
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a larger substring? Like `writer.Write(line2.Substring(match2.Index + 11, 20));`

Comment: No... it will include the newline,  but i want each game for each line, and also not exactly the team name

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I need to get attribute from <span>,  like【<span>Swansea City</span>】, but don't know how

Comment: yes, but what have you *tried*?

Comment: I use regex like 【<span>.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?</span>】that suitable for any team name but it takes too long time for comparing

Comment: use `.+` instead of `.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?`. Alternatively, you could try using an XML Parser

Comment: OK, that's work, thank u!

Comment: Great! I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `.+` in your RegEx, instead of `.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?.?`.

For more info, take a look at this [website](https://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).